# The problem with movement and shooting in the python game

Tags: python

I wrote a simple python game, there are no errors in the code, but for some reason I can't move and shoot, I tried all the options, even I contacted the gpt chat and it didn't help(

I tried all the options, only the arrow control came up, but I still couldn't shoot. I need to control the keys W A S D, and shooting with the left mouse button

code is here:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random
import math
import time

# Инициализация Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Click to Kill")

# Параметры экрана
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

# Цвета
WHITE = "white"
RED = "red"
ORANGE = "orange"

# Игровые параметры
player_radius = 20
enemy_radius = 15
boss_radius = 30
bullet_radius = 5
player_speed = 5
bullet_speed = 10
enemy_speed = 3
max_enemies = 6
boss_spawn_rate = 10
score = 0
player_lives = 10
knockback_distance = 40
shots_to_kill_enemy = 3
shots_to_kill_boss = 5
enemies_killed = 0

# Игровые объекты
player = canvas.create_oval(WIDTH // 2 - player_radius, HEIGHT // 2 - player_radius,
                            WIDTH // 2 + player_radius, HEIGHT // 2 + player_radius, fill=WHITE)
bullets = []
enemies = []
bosses = []

# Таймер
start_time = time.time()
immortal_timer = 0
immortal_duration = 500

# Окно игры
game_window = (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
window_shrink_speed = 0.05

# Флаги для отслеживания нажатия и отпускания клавиш
move_left = False
move_right = False
move_up = False
move_down = False
mouse_button_pressed = False
can_shoot = True

# Флаг для отслеживания состояния игры
game_over = False

def mouse_click(event):
    global mouse_button_pressed, can_shoot
    mouse_button_pressed = True
    can_shoot = True

def mouse_release(event):
    global mouse_button_pressed
    mouse_button_pressed = False

def restart_game(event):
    global player_lives, score, enemies_killed, immortal_timer, start_time, player, bullets, enemies, bosses, game_over
    player_lives = 10
    score = 0
    enemies_killed = 0
    immortal_timer = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    canvas.coords(player, WIDTH // 2 - player_radius, HEIGHT // 2 - player_radius,
                WIDTH // 2 + player_radius, HEIGHT // 2 + player_radius)
    bullets = []
    enemies = []
    bosses = []
    game_over = False

root.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_click)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", mouse_release)
root.bind("<Return>", restart_game)

def key_press(event):
    global move_left, move_right, move_up, move_down

    if event.keysym == "a":
        move_left = True
    elif event.keysym == "d":
        move_right = True
    elif event.keysym == "w":
        move_up = True
    elif event.keysym == "s":
        move_down = True

def key_release(event):
    global move_left, move_right, move_up, move_down

    if event.keysym == "a":
        move_left = False
    elif event.keysym == "d":
        move_right = False
    elif event.keysym == "w":
        move_up = False
    elif event.keysym == "s":
        move_down = False

root.bind("<KeyPress>", key_press)
root.bind("<KeyRelease>", key_release)

def update_game():
    global player_lives, score, enemies_killed, immortal_timer, start_time, player, bullets, enemies, bosses, game_over, can_shoot

    if not game_over:
        player_movement = [move_left, move_right, move_up, move_down]

        # Движение игрока
        new_player_x = canvas.coords(player)[0] + (player_movement[1] - player_movement[0]) * player_speed
        new_player_y = canvas.coords(player)[1] + (player_movement[3] - player_movement[2]) * player_speed

        # Проверка на выход за границы экрана
        new_player_x = max(min(new_player_x, WIDTH - player_radius * 2), 0)
        new_player_y = max(min(new_player_y, HEIGHT - player_radius * 2), 0)

        # Проверка столкновения с врагами
        player_rect = (new_player_x, new_player_y, new_player_x + player_radius * 2, new_player_y + player_radius * 2)
        for enemy in enemies:
            if canvas.coords(enemy)[0] < player_rect[2] and canvas.coords(enemy)[2] > player_rect[0] and \
                    canvas.coords(enemy)[1] < player_rect[3] and canvas.coords(enemy)[3] > player_rect[1] and immortal_timer == 0:
                direction = math.atan2(new_player_y + player_radius - (canvas.coords(enemy)[1] + enemy_radius),
                                        new_player_x + player_radius - (canvas.coords(enemy)[0] + enemy_radius))

                # Отбрасывание игрока
                new_player_x += math.cos(direction) * knockback_distance
                new_player_y += math.sin(direction) * knockback_distance

                immortal_timer = time.time()
                player_lives -= 1

                if player_lives == 0:
                    game_over = True

        # Проверка времени бессмертия
        if immortal_timer != 0 and time.time() - immortal_timer >= immortal_duration:
            immortal_timer = 0

        # Обновление координат игрока
        canvas.coords(player, new_player_x, new_player_y, new_player_x + player_radius * 2, new_player_y + player_radius * 2)

        # Стрельба
        if mouse_button_pressed and can_shoot:
            angle = math.atan2(root.winfo_pointery() - (new_player_y + player_radius),
                                root.winfo_pointerx() - (new_player_x + player_radius))
            bullets.append((new_player_x + player_radius, new_player_y + player_radius, angle))
            can_shoot = False

        # Движение пуль
        active_bullets = []
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet_x = bullet[0] + math.cos(bullet[2]) * bullet_speed
            bullet_y = bullet[1] + math.sin(bullet[2]) * bullet_speed

            # Проверка на выход за границы экрана
            if 0 <= bullet_x <= WIDTH and 0 <= bullet_y <= HEIGHT:
                active_bullets.append((bullet_x, bullet_y, bullet[2]))

        bullets = active_bullets

        # Спаун врагов
        if len(enemies) < max_enemies and random.randint(1, boss_spawn_rate) != 1:
            enemy_x = random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_radius * 2)
            enemy_y = random.choice([-enemy_radius * 2, HEIGHT])
            new_enemy = canvas.create_polygon(enemy_x, enemy_y + enemy_radius * 2,
                                                    enemy_x + enemy_radius, enemy_y,
                                                    enemy_x + enemy_radius * 2, enemy_y + enemy_radius * 2, fill=RED)
            enemies.append(new_enemy)
        elif len(bosses) == 0 and enemies_killed >= 10 and random.randint(1, boss_spawn_rate) == 1:
            boss_x = random.randint(0, WIDTH - boss_radius * 2)
            boss_y = random.choice([-boss_radius * 2, HEIGHT])
            new_boss = canvas.create_rectangle(boss_x, boss_y, boss_x + boss_radius * 2, boss_y + boss_radius * 2, fill=ORANGE)
            bosses.append(new_boss)

            # Сброс счетчика убитых врагов после спауна босса
            enemies_killed = 0

        # Движение врагов
        for enemy in enemies:
            direction = math.atan2(new_player_y + player_radius - (canvas.coords(enemy)[1] + enemy_radius),
                                        new_player_x + player_radius - (canvas.coords(enemy)[0] + enemy_radius))

            # Двигаем врагов в их направлении, но только если нет столкновения с игроком
            enemy_rect = canvas.coords(enemy)
            if not (enemy_rect[0] < player_rect[2] and enemy_rect[2] > player_rect[0] and
                    enemy_rect[1] < player_rect[3] and enemy_rect[3] > player_rect[1]):
                canvas.move(enemy, math.cos(direction) * enemy_speed, math.sin(direction) * enemy_speed)

        # Движение боссов
        for boss in bosses:
            direction = math.atan2(new_player_y + player_radius - (canvas.coords(boss)[1] + boss_radius),
                                    new_player_x + player_radius - (canvas.coords(boss)[0] + boss_radius))

            # Двигаем боссов в их направлении, но только если нет столкновения с игроком
            boss_rect = canvas.coords(boss)
            if not (boss_rect[0] < player_rect[2] and boss_rect[2] > player_rect[0] and
                    boss_rect[1] < player_rect[3] and boss_rect[3] > player_rect[1]):
                canvas.move(boss, math.cos(direction) * enemy_speed, math.sin(direction) * enemy_speed)

        # Проверка столкновения пуль с врагами и боссами
        bullets_to_remove = []
        for bullet in bullets:
            should_remove_bullet = False
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy_rect = canvas.coords(enemy)
                if enemy_rect[0] < bullet[0] < enemy_rect[2] and enemy_rect[1] < bullet[1] < enemy_rect[3]:
                    should_remove_bullet = True

                    # Попадание врага
                    enemies_killed += 1
                    score += 1

                    canvas.delete(enemy)

            # Проверка столкновения пуль с боссами
            for boss in bosses:
                boss_rect = canvas.coords(boss)
                if boss_rect[0] < bullet[0] < boss_rect[2] and boss_rect[1] < bullet[1] < boss_rect[3]:
                    should_remove_bullet = True

                    # Попадание босса
                    score += 5

                    canvas.delete(boss)

            if not should_remove_bullet:
                bullets_to_remove.append(bullet)

        # Удаление пуль
        bullets = bullets_to_remove

        # Проверка столкновения игрока с окном
        if not (game_window[0] < player_rect[2] < game_window[2] and
                game_window[1] < player_rect[3] < game_window[3]):
            game_over = True

        # Отображение счета и жизней
        score_text = tk.Label(root, text=f"Очки: {score}", font=("Arial", 14), fg=WHITE, bg="black")
        score_text.place(x=10, y=10)

        lives_text = tk.Label(root, text=f"Жизни: {player_lives}/10", font=("Arial", 14), fg=WHITE, bg="black")
        lives_text.place(x=WIDTH - 170, y=10)

        # Отображение времени игры
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = (current_time - start_time)
        minutes = int(elapsed_time // 60)
        seconds = int(elapsed_time % 60)
        milliseconds = int((elapsed_time * 100) % 100)
        timer_text = tk.Label(root, text=f"Время: {minutes:02}:{seconds:02}.{milliseconds:02}", font=("Arial", 14), fg=WHITE, bg="black")
        timer_text.place(x=WIDTH - 195, y=50)
    else:
        # Отображение сообщения о проигрыше и результатов
        game_over_text = tk.Label(root, text="Ты проиграл, лох!", font=("Arial", 28), fg=WHITE, bg="black")
        game_over_text.place(x=WIDTH // 2 - game_over_text.winfo_reqwidth() // 2, y=HEIGHT // 4)

        result_text = tk.Label(root, text=f"Очки: {score}  |  Время: {minutes:02}:{seconds:02}.{milliseconds:02}", font=("Arial", 14), fg=WHITE, bg="black")
        result_text.place(x=WIDTH // 2 - result_text.winfo_reqwidth() // 2, y=HEIGHT // 2)

        restart_text = tk.Label(root, text="Нажмите Enter, чтобы начать заново", font=("Arial", 14), fg=WHITE, bg="black")
        restart_text.place(x=WIDTH // 2 - restart_text.winfo_reqwidth() // 2, y=HEIGHT * 3 // 4)

    root.after(30, update_game)

# Запуск игрового цикла
update_game()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We need to see your code (as a [mcve]) if you want help with your code.

Answer (score 0):

`update_game()` is only handling the bullet movement in the function

```
# Bullet movement
        active_bullets = []
        print("active_bullets :",active_bullets)
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet_x = bullet[0] + math.cos(bullet[2]) * bullet_speed
            bullet_y = bullet[1] + math.sin(bullet[2]) * bullet_speed

            # Check for out-of-screen boundaries
            if 0 <= bullet_x <= WIDTH and 0 <= bullet_y <= HEIGHT:
                active_bullets.append((bullet_x, bullet_y, bullet[2]))

        bullets = active_bullets
```

does not handle the rendering of the bullets

```
# Render bullets
        for bullet in bullets:
            x, y, _ = bullet  # Extract bullet position (ignore angle for rendering)
            canvas.create_oval(x - bullet_radius, y - bullet_radius,x + bullet_radius, y + bullet_radius,fill="yellow")  #appearance of the bullet
```

Comment: it turns out a mixture of bullets that remain in the window and do not cause damage